# How to write to MongoDB asynchronously with Apache Camel

Tags: spring, mongodb, apache-camel, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'd like to know if it is possible to write to MongoDB with Apache Camel and choose to write asynchronously. I've seen no reference for the [MongoDB Java Reactive Streams Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/reactive-streams/), but I'd like to know if there's also an option of writing to MongoDB with Apache Camel with the Reactive driver (for Project Reactor users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *MongoDB* producer *Apache Camel* component uses the [**Sync - MongoDB Java Driver**](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/current/) by default.

A component in *Apache Camel* runs as is and cannot be modified unless through a predefined set of configuration options.

To achieve multi-threading, you can decouple the continuation of message routing from consuming thread using the **Threads EIP patten**:

```
from("direct:operation")
    .threads(1)
    .to("mongodb:myDb?database=someDb&collection=someCollection&operation=save")
```

You can read more on [the supported options](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/threads-eip.html#_options) in the documentation.

Comment: So in general Apache Camel isn't flexible enough to work seamlessly asynchronously? As for my understanding, I'd better off using a different and more async-friendly library like Spring Integration if I want better performance. An I right?